# what are the typical loss function for multi-label classification with dependent classes

Tags: classification, multilabel

For multi-label (multi-class) classification task, it seems to me that the standard loss to use is the binary cross entropy loss. However, it assumes that the the classes are independent and we are basically training one cross entropy for each class and summing them up.

I am wondering how to handle the scenario where the classes are not independent. For example, in image classification, some labels are more likely to show up together (e.g. tree, flower) while other labels could be mutually exclusive (e.g. polar bear, forest).

Comment: The question what would you want to in the case of mutually exclusive classes? Like what would you expect the loss function to do in that case?

Comment: if all classes are mutually exclusive, the problem becomes multi-class classification and we will just use categorical cross entropy? i've seen people using categorical cross-entropy on multi-label problem (which is counter-intuitive but seems to achieve better results)

Comment: I  have never seen that. Although the opposite where people use BCE for multitask Problems.

Comment: In this paper "Exploring the Limits of Weakly Supervised Pretraining" by FB, they used categorical CE and got better results compare to BCE

Comment: That is indeed very interesting